# C++ iteration, file i/o

Tags: c++, file, io, iteration

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Input .txt file
    ifstream inputFile ("input.txt");

    try
    {
        int i = 1;  //Line iterator
        int vertices = 0;
        int faces = 0;

        string line;
        while (getline(inputFile, line))
        {
            //Take number from line 4, set as variable "vertices"
            if (i == 3)
            {
                getline (inputFile,line); 
                size_t last_index = line.find_last_not_of("0123456789");  
                string str = line.substr(last_index);
                vertices = atoi(str.c_str());  //Convert to int
                cout << "vertices " + str << endl;
            }

            //Take number from line 11, set as variable "triangles"
            if (i == 11)
            {
                getline (inputFile,line); 
                size_t last_index = line.find_last_not_of("0123456789");
                string str = line.substr(last_index);
                faces = atoi(str.c_str());           //Convert to int
                cout << "faces " + str << endl;
            }

            if (i == 13)
            {
                i++;
                break;
            }

            cout << "line: " + i << endl;  //Prints line number
            i++;

        }
    } catch(const char* error) {
        cout << "Cannot read file, please try again." << error;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This program is simply trying to read file, take a number from a couple of lines and for each line print "line: " with respective line number. It looks like C++ iterates differently to Java?
For some reason this program outputs:

```
*ine: 
ne: 
vertices  752
e: 
: 

Cannot read mesh, please try again.
faces r
annot read mesh, please try again.
nnot read mesh, please try again.*
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: you know you are reading and discrading the first line from the file in the loop condition?

Comment: Why does your code say "Cannot read file" but your output says "Cannot read mesh"?

Comment: @stardust_ He's also using the results of `getline` without testing whether it succeeded.

Comment: I changed the error message, sorry for the confusion

Comment: @stardust_ No, I didn't know that, but that explains some other things, how can I fix that?

Comment: @user2136754. It is easy. Definitely you can remove the getlines() in the if conditions and use the line you have read in the while(). it is the same thing. You just have to modify the if conditions a bit. For exaple instead of i==3 it will be i==4 now. But you can figure that out, at least by trial end error.

Comment: Avoid `endl`. Use `'\n'` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
cout << "line: " + i << endl;
```

should be:

```
cout << "line: " << i << endl;
```

Your `+` is adding `i` to the string constant `"line: "`, which has the effect of knocking one character off the front each time round the loop (and eventually going off the end, leading to undefined behaviour).

You can't add objects to strings in C++ in the way you're attempting, but you can send multiple objects to `cout` by repeated use of `<<`.

You then have the same problem here:

```
cout << "vertices " + str << endl;
```

and here:

```
cout << "faces " + str << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks, just not used to C++